# Is it true that for complex $s$: $\lim\limits_{s\to 1} \frac{2-2^s}{s-1}=-2\log (2)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Is it true that for complex $s$,

$$\lim_{s\to 1} \frac{2-2^s}{s-1}=-2\log (2)?$$

If so, prove it.

Comment: This is a piece of a problem from a Number Thoery book Im working through.  I dont know much Complex Analysis.  Any suggested books?

Comment: Dunno, I've only picked it up here and there. It's possible you could get the fundamentals down through lecture notes and pdfs and Wikipedia and such. Number theory (of the not-elementary sort), especially analytic NT, utilizes complex analysis a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is true.

**Added:**  The nicest solution is to just note that the above is the definition of the derivative.

**Hint:** Use l'Hopitals rule.  Make sure you can justify why this is allowed now that we are dealing with complex numbers.

**Alternative Hint:** Use power series.  Since $2^s$ is analytic everywhere, we can expand around $s=1$ and write it as $$2e^{(s-1)\log 2}=2+2(s-1)\log 2+2\frac{(s-1)^2}{2!}\log^2 2+\cdots $$  From this you can deduce the Laurent series around $s=1$ for $\frac{2-2^s}{s-1}.$

Comment: Since the limit we're trying to calculate is, by definition, the derivative of $-2^s$ at 1, it seems silly to use a method that requires you already to know this derivative.

Comment: Dear Eric, To amplify @Chris's point, one can see that this is (by definition) computing the derivative of $-2^s$ at $s = 1$, and hence compute it directly.  There is no need to mention L'Hopital.  Regards,

Comment: The factor of $2$ seems to have disappeared from all but the lead term of your series. I would have answered as in your Alternate Hint. However, for analytic functions, l'Hopital's rule is indeed valid.